# How do I cast a 2D list to a void pointer and back

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I'm trying to write two Cython functions to wrap external functions. The functions are the inverse of each another; one accepts a string, and returns a struct with two fields: a void pointer to a 2D array (the second dimension is always two elements: `[[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0], … ]`), and the array's length. The other accepts the same struct, and returns a string. So far, I've got the following. It compiles, but the cast to and from the nested list is definitely incorrect.

My `.pxd`:

```
cdef extern from "header.h":
    struct _FFIArray:
        void* data
        size_t len

    cdef _FFIArray decode_polyline_ffi(char* polyline, int precision);
    cdef char* encode_coordinates_ffi(_FFIArray, int precision);
    cdef void drop_float_array(_FFIArray coords);
    cdef void drop_cstring(char* polyline)
```

My `.pyx`:

```
import numpy as np
from pypolyline_p cimport (
    _FFIArray,
    decode_polyline_ffi,
    encode_coordinates_ffi,
    drop_float_array,
    drop_cstring
    )

def encode_coordinates(coords, int precision):
    """ coords looks like [[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], …] """
    cdef double[::1] ncoords = np.array(coords, dtype=np.float64)
    cdef _FFIArray coords_ffi
    # Wrong
    coords_ffi.data = <void*>&ncoords[0]
    # Wrong
    coords_ffi.len = ncoords.shape[0]
    cdef char* result = encode_coordinates_ffi(coords_ffi, precision)
    cdef bytes polyline = result
    drop_cstring(result)
    return polyline

def decode_polyline(bytes polyline, int precision):
    cdef char* to_send = polyline
    cdef _FFIArray result = decode_polyline_ffi(to_send, precision)
    # Wrong
    cdef double* incoming_ptr = <double*>(result.data)
    # Wrong
    cdef double[::1] view = <double[:result.len:1]>incoming_ptr
    coords = np.copy(view)
    drop_float_array(result)
    return coords
```

Comment: You're trying to describe a 2D array using only a single length... How do you expect it to know the size of the other dimension? (is it always 2?)

Comment: @davidw Sorry, should have been clear: the other dimension is always 2 elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're trying to use 2D arrays and 1D memoryviews

In the encoding function

```
    # the coords are a 2D, C contiguous array
    cdef double[:,::1] ncoords = np.array(coords, dtype=np.float64)
    # ...
    coords_ffi.data = <void*>&ncoords[0,0] # take the 0,0 element
    # the rest stays the same
```

In the decoding function

```
   # specify it as a 2D, len by 2, C contiguous array
   cdef double[:,::1] view = <double[:result.len,:2:1]>incoming_ptr
   # the rest stays the same
```

(It's possible that your FFI functions expect Fortran contiguous arrays. In which case the `::1` goes on the first dimension of the memoryview, and you also change `incoming_ptr`)

Comment: I think this is right. It's difficult to test without the interface that wants to use it though.

Comment: This works perfectly. I changed the cdef in the decoding function to `cdef double[:, ::1] view = …` to match the one in the encoding function…

Comment: Good spot - I missed that one. I've edited the answer so it's right (but given you already found it you don't need to know that!)